# Weird errors with scripts in iframe

Tags: html

This is the iframe html:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js;script-src https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js;" />
</head>

<body>
    <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
</body>
```

For some reason it's displaying these errors:
`Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js”.`
`Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js (“script-src”).`

I tried to add the content security policy thing on the  element but it didn't look like it affected it, and I have a similiar content security policy on the document that holds the iframe.

Comment: Did you get that error message **before** you added `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" ...>`?

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: @Quentin I got that error message after and before, it seemed like the content security policy did not do anything...